# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIds' of undefined at window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-cordova, onesignal

I have a cordova project in my Visual Studio 2017. If I run ***cordova requirements*** I get the followin:

*Java JDK: installed 1.8.0 

Android SDK: installed 

Android target: installed android-19,android-21,android-22,android-23,android-26,Google Inc.:Google APIs:19,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23 

Gradle: installed*

Debugging in chrome work perfectly, but in my device I get the followin error:

**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIds' of undefined".**

That is a fragment of my javascript code:

```
function registerOneSignalDevice(callback) {

    window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function (ids) {

        setStorage("device_id", ids.userId);
        setStorage("device_platform", device.platform);
        if (callback != undefined) {
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Any idea...

Comment: Try using if and check for Onesignal ! = undefined

Comment: Thanks for answering, when I check your suggestion return that OneSigna is undefined..Could be because of my version of Cordova, currently it is 6.3.1, installed by default by visual studio 2017.

Comment: In this case there are any psibility to upgrade the cordova version in Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OneSignal recommends using Cordova 6.4.0 or newer. You may want to update to the latest OneSignal Cordova SDK as well.

The getIds method was deprecated in the 2.1.0 release. You should update to their SDK 2.2.5

For Cordova and variant SDKs like ionic, Phonegap and IntelXDK you can get the UserIds aka PlayerIds using the getPermissionSubscriptionState method and addSubscriptionObserver.

For more on using getPermissionSubscriptionState see: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk#section--getpermissionsubscriptionstate-

For adding subscription observers see: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk#section--addsubscriptionobserver-